# Задача на Codewars: Sorting by bits

Tags: javascript, массивы, разрешение

Решаю задачу по JS на codewars (ссылка: https://www.codewars.com/kata/59fa8e2646d8433ee200003f/train/javascript).

Мой код:

```
function sortByBit(arr) {
  function countDigits(cd) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < cd.length; i++) {
      sum += parseInt(cd[i]);
    }
    return sum;
  }
  return arr.sort((a, b) => a - b).sort((a, b) => {
    return countDigits(parseInt(a).toString(2)) - countDigits(parseInt(b).toString(2));
  });

}
```

Тестил код в консоле VScode и консоли браузера Chrome. Результат: решение правильное. Но почему-то, при тестировании решения на codewars выходит ошибка, решение неверно.

Expected: [0, 2, 2, 4, 8, 8, 3, 5, 5, 6, 9, 7, 56], instead got: [0, 2, 4, 2, 8, 8, 3, 6, 9, 5, 5, 7, 56].

В консоли VSCode и Chrome у меня выходит правильный результат: [0, 2, 2, 4, 8, 8, 3, 5, 5, 6, 9, 7, 56].

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Два последовательных вызова `sort` - фигня, потому что js не гарантирует стабильную сортировку.

Comment: Что делать тогда? Сортировка раздельно ситуацию не улучшает.

Comment: @ZhenyaM., открыть ссылку и прочитать.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/708570)

Comment: @Dmitry, является.

Comment: @Qwertiy пускай так. Я поражаюсь качеству ответа